# Outdent in TextMate not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate, indentation

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> work just fine when I indent, but <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> just seems to delete the code that I've highlighted. How do I outdent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To indent and outdent, I use <kbd>Apple</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>[</kbd>.

Comment: not sure why I got a -1 here... answered rapidly and correctly.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_text), <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> should decrease or increase the indentation level respectively.

However, if you search tha that page for the following text:

> 4.6.1 Increase/Decrease Indent Level

...you will see that <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> *should* work, at least on European keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't know you could do that. Well, it works on my installation so something has changed. OK not much help but try

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> for outdent
and
<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> for indent